# getActivity returns null in ActivityUnitTestCase

Tags: android, android-testing

How to get an activity in android test, if  getActivity() always returns null?

```
public class PageDistrListTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<PageDistrList> {

PageDistrList activity;

  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        activity = getActivity();
        headerRecycler = (RecyclerView) activity.findViewById(R.id.page_tab_distr_recycler_header);
    }
}
```

Comment: try using either robolectric or mochito.

Answer (score 1):

You will get activity instance like this

```
activity = launchActivity("package.PageDistrList", PageDistrList.class, null);
```

I am not sure of this.Please feel free to correct me.